# Android - Creating Listview using Custom Adapter Programmatically

Tags: android, custom-adapter, sql-server-data-services

I'm in learning about add view programmatically. But, I'm in confusing now. 
I have data, there are idpatient, idheader. Patient can have more than one ID header. When I input idpatient, it will add listview (with custom adapter) programmatically. The number of listview is same with the number of ID header.

I want to set in each listview with data patient group by ID header.. 
So far, I add search view when loop adding listview, but when I input one ID header to seacrh view, all of listview will view the same data according to ID header in search view..

I'm sorry for the long explanation. Can anybody help me to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance

[image]

This is My Adapter :

```
/**
 * Created by RKI on 11/9/2016.
 */
  public class AdapterHistory extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable,   View.OnClickListener {
    private Activity activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    HistoryHeaderActivity main;
    public int count = 0;
    Context context;
    public ModelHistory product;
    ArrayList<ModelHistory> mStringFilterList;
    ModelHistory tempValues = null;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;
    public Cart cart;

    public AdapterHistory(HistoryHeaderActivity main, ArrayList<ModelHistory> arraylist) {
        this.main = main;
        this.main.historyModel = arraylist;
        mStringFilterList = arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return main.historyModel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return main.historyModel.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int pos = position;
        final Cart carts = CartHelper.getCart();
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolderItem holder = new ViewHolderItem();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) main.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_history, null);
            holder.h_id = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.id_header_);
            holder.h_type = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.servicetype_);
            holder.h_qty = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.qty_);
            holder.h_ps_id = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.patient_id);
            holder.h_ps_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.patient_);
            holder.h_dokid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.doctor_id_);
            holder.h_dokname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.doctor_);
            holder.h_item = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_);
            holder.h_date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date_);
            holder.checkToCart = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.checkToCart.setTag(position);
            holder.checkToCart.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    tempValues.setSelected(isChecked);
                }
            });
            vi.setTag(holder);
            vi.setTag(R.id.checkBox, holder.checkToCart);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolderItem) vi.getTag();
        }
        if (main.historyModel.size() <= 0) {
            holder.h_date.setText("No Data");

        } else {
            /*** Get each Model object from Arraylist ****/
            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = (ModelHistory) main.historyModel.get(position);
            holder.h_id.setText(tempValues.getH_id());
            holder.h_type.setText(tempValues.getH_service());
            holder.h_qty.setText(tempValues.getH_qty());
            holder.h_ps_name.setText(tempValues.getH_p_name());
            holder.h_ps_id.setText(tempValues.getH_p_id());
            holder.h_dokid.setText(tempValues.getH_d_id());
            holder.h_dokname.setText(tempValues.getH_d_name());
            holder.h_item.setText(tempValues.getH_item());
            holder.h_date.setText(tempValues.getH_date());
            holder.checkToCart.setTag(position);
            holder.checkToCart.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    main.historyModel.get(position).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });
            holder.checkToCart.setChecked(main.historyModel.get(position).isSelected());
            for (pos = 1; pos <= 1; pos++) {
                main.u_pname = tempValues.getH_p_name();
                main.u_pid = tempValues.getH_p_id();
                main.u_service = tempValues.getH_service();
                main.up_iddetail = tempValues.getH_id();
            }
        }
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    public static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView h_id, h_type, h_ps_id, h_ps_name, h_dokid, h_dokname, h_item, h_qty, h_date;
        CheckBox checkToCart;
    }

    private List<TransactionsItem> getCartItems(Cart cart) {
        List<TransactionsItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Saleable, Integer> itemMap = cart.getItemWithQuantity();

        for (Map.Entry<Saleable, Integer> entry : itemMap.entrySet()) {
            TransactionsItem cartItem = new TransactionsItem();
            cartItem.setProduct((ModelInventory) entry.getKey());
            cartItem.setQuantity(entry.getValue());
            cartItems.add(cartItem);
        }

        return cartItems;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                List<ModelHistory> filterList = new ArrayList<ModelHistory>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_id().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        ModelHistory country = new ModelHistory(
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_id(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_p_id(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_date(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_p_name(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_d_id(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_d_name(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_item(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_qty(),
                                mStringFilterList.get(i).getH_service());
                        filterList.add(country);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            main.historyModel = (ArrayList<ModelHistory>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This is My Activity :

```
import com.mobileproject.rki.mobile_his_receipt.view.adapter.AdapterHistory;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class HistoryHeaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    static final String URL = "http://.../GetDataInv";
    static final String KEY_TABLE = "Table"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_REG_ID = "Sales_Aptk_ID", KEY_DATE = "Sales_Aptk_Date",
            KEY_PATIENT_ID = "Sales_Aptk_Patient_ID", KEY_SERVICE_ID = "Sales_Aptk_Type",
            KEY_PATIENT_NAME = "Sales_Aptk_Patient_Name",
            KEY_DOCTOR_ID = "Sales_Aptk_Doctor_ID", KEY_DOCTOR_NAME = "Sales_Aptk_Doctor_Name",
            KEY_ITEM_ID = "Sales_Aptk_Detail_Item_ID", KEY_DETAIL_UNIT = "Sales_Aptk_Detail_Unit",
            KEY_ITEM_QTY = "Sales_Aptk_Detail_Qty";
    static final String KEY_ID_HEADER = "Sales_Aptk_ID";

    static final String KEY_TABLE_INV = "Table"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ITEM_ID_INV = "Item_ID", KEY_ITEM_NAME = "Item_Name",
            KEY_MAX_STOCK = "Item_Max_Stock";

    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_DATA_PROGRESS = 0, DIALOG_NO_DATA = 1,
            DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_FULL_PHOTO_PROGRESS = 2;

    Element e;
    final Context context = this;
    public List<ModelInventory> invModels;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public static String id, up_iddetail, up_user, u_pid, u_pname, u_service, xml;
    public ArrayList<ModelInventory> invModel = new ArrayList<ModelInventory>();
    public ArrayList<ModelHistory> historyModel = new ArrayList<ModelHistory>();
    public ArrayList<ModelIDHeader> headerModel = new ArrayList<ModelIDHeader>();
    public Cart cart;
    private Menu menu;
    AdapterHistory hstAdpt, idhstAdpt;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public ModelInventory productInv;
    int mPosition, invPosition;
    EditText p_id;
    ListView listHistory;
    XMLParser parser;
    LinearLayout lm;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history_header);

        lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        p_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.patientID);
        listHistory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listhistory);

        hstAdpt = new AdapterHistory(HistoryHeaderActivity.this, historyModel);
        listHistory.setAdapter(hstAdpt);


        listHistory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mPosition = position;
                invPosition = position;
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences login2 = getSharedPreferences("USERLOGIN", 0);
        String doktername = login2.getString("userlogin", "0");
        up_user = doktername;

        p_id.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                onGetHistory();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Check Form Input
     *
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isFormValid() {
        String aTemp = p_id.getText().toString();

        if (aTemp.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Input Patient ID..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        } else {
            id = aTemp.toString();
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void dismissDialogWait() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onGetHistory() {
        listHistory.setAdapter(null);
        if (isFormValid()) {
            GetDataHistoryTask syncTask = new GetDataHistoryTask();
            syncTask.execute(new IntroductingMethod());

            GetDataHeaderTask syncTaskHeader = new GetDataHeaderTask();
            syncTaskHeader.execute(new IntroductingMethod());
        }
    }

    private class GetDataHistoryTask extends AsyncTask<IntroductingMethod, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(IntroductingMethod... params) {
            IntroductingMethod REGService = params[0];
            return REGService.getHistoryData(id);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dismissDialogWait();

            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                    }
                    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(result); // getting DOM element

                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TABLE);
                    // looping through all item nodes <item>
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                        ModelHistory add = new ModelHistory();
                        add.setH_id(parser.getValue(e, KEY_REG_ID));
                        add.setH_p_name(parser.getValue(e, KEY_PATIENT_NAME));
                        add.setH_p_id(parser.getValue(e, KEY_PATIENT_ID));
                        add.setH_service(parser.getValue(e, KEY_SERVICE_ID));
                        add.setH_date(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));
                        add.setH_detail_unit(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DETAIL_UNIT));
                        add.setH_d_id(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DOCTOR_ID));
                        add.setH_d_name(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DOCTOR_NAME));
                        add.setH_item(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_ID));
                        add.setH_qty(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_QTY));
                        historyModel.add(add);
                    }
                    ShowAllContentHistory();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(HistoryHeaderActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                            "Koneksi gagal. Silahkan coba kembali.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HistoryHeaderActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Koneksi gagal. Silahkan coba kembali.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class GetDataHeaderTask extends AsyncTask<IntroductingMethod, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(IntroductingMethod... params) {
            IntroductingMethod REGService = params[0];
            return REGService.getHistoryHeaderData(id);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dismissDialogWait();

            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                    }
                    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(result); // getting DOM element

                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TABLE);
                    // looping through all item nodes <item>
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                        ModelIDHeader add = new ModelIDHeader();
                        add.setIdSalesHeader(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID_HEADER));
                        headerModel.add(add);
                    }
                    if(result.contains("<Sales_Aptk_Patient_ID>"+id+"</Sales_Aptk_Patient_ID>")){
                    Log.d("NilaiID ", id);
                        AddNewList();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("Kenapayahh", id);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(HistoryHeaderActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                            "Koneksi gagal. Silahkan coba kembali.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HistoryHeaderActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Koneksi gagal. Silahkan coba kembali.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    public void AskUpdate(View v) {
        if (hstAdpt.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(HistoryHeaderActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                    "Tidak ada rekaman pasien.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            SharedPreferences id_header = getSharedPreferences("IDSALESAPTK", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorID = id_header.edit();
            editorID.putString("idsalesaptk", up_iddetail);
            editorID.commit();

            SharedPreferences sendPref2 = getSharedPreferences("DATAPATIENTNAME", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sendPref2.edit();
            editor2.putString("datapatientname", u_pname);
            editor2.commit();
            editor2.clear();

            SharedPreferences sendPref3 = getSharedPreferences("DATAPATIENTID", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = sendPref3.edit();
            editor3.putString("datapatientid", u_pid);
            editor3.commit();
            editor3.clear();

            SharedPreferences regID = getSharedPreferences("DATAREGID", 0);
            String reg_ID = regID.getString("dataregid", "0");
            SharedPreferences sendPref4 = getSharedPreferences("DATAREGID", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor4 = sendPref4.edit();
            editor4.putString("dataregid", reg_ID);
            editor4.commit();
            editor4.clear();

            SharedPreferences sendPref1 = getSharedPreferences("DATASERVICE", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sendPref1.edit();
            editor1.putString("dataservice", u_service);
            editor1.commit();
            editor1.clear();
            new LoadingDataAsync().execute();
        }
    }


    public class LoadingDataAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            updateDetail();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_DATA_PROGRESS);
            removeDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_DATA_PROGRESS);
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_DATA_PROGRESS);
        }
    }

    public void updateDetail() {
        ArrayList<ModelHistory> candidateModelArrayList = new ArrayList<ModelHistory>();
        for (ModelHistory model : historyModel) {
            if (model.isSelected()) {
                candidateModelArrayList.add(model);
            }
        }

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        parser = new XMLParser();
        xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TABLE_INV);
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            ModelInventory add = new ModelInventory();
            add.setItem_ID(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_ID_INV));
            add.setItem_Name(parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_NAME));
            add.setItem_Max_Stock(parser.getValue(e, KEY_MAX_STOCK));
            invModel.add(add);
        }
        invModels = new ArrayList<ModelInventory>();
        invModels = invModel;
        ArrayAdapter<ModelInventory> adptInv = new ArrayAdapter<ModelInventory>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, invModels);
        ArrayAdapter<ModelHistory> adptChkItem = new ArrayAdapter<ModelHistory>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, candidateModelArrayList);
        if (adptInv.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(HistoryHeaderActivity.this, "Empty Patient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        cart = CartHelper.getCart();
        for (mPosition = 0; mPosition < adptChkItem.getCount(); mPosition++) {
            ModelHistory historyItem = (ModelHistory) adptChkItem.getItem(mPosition);
            for (int j = mPosition; j < adptInv.getCount(); j++) {
                ModelInventory inventoryItem = (ModelInventory) adptInv.getItem(j);
                if (candidateModelArrayList.get(mPosition).getH_item().equals(inventoryItem.getItem_ID())) {
                    if (cart.getProducts().toString().contains(inventoryItem.getItem_Name())) {
                    } else {
                        productInv = (ModelInventory) (Serializable) adptInv.getItem(j);
                        int qty = Integer.parseInt(historyItem.getH_qty());
                        cart.add(productInv, qty);
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CartActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("PersonID", "try");
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        hstAdpt.getFilter().filter(newText);
        idhstAdpt.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

    public void AddNewList(){
        ArrayAdapter<ModelIDHeader> adptIDHeader = new ArrayAdapter<ModelIDHeader>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, headerModel);

        for(int count =0; count< adptIDHeader.getCount(); count++){
            idhstAdpt = new AdapterHistory(HistoryHeaderActivity.this, historyModel);
            ModelIDHeader idHeader = (ModelIDHeader) adptIDHeader.getItem(count);

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setId(count);
            btn.setText(idHeader.getIdSalesHeader());
            lm.addView(btn);

            SearchView search = new SearchView(this);
            search.setQuery(idHeader.getIdSalesHeader(), false);
            search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            lm.addView(search);

            ListView tv = new ListView(this);
            tv.setId(count);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setDividerHeight(2);
            tv.setAdapter(idhstAdpt);
            lm.addView(tv);

        }
    }

    public void ShowAllContentHistory() {
        listHistory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listhistory);
        hstAdpt = new AdapterHistory(HistoryHeaderActivity.this, historyModel);
        listHistory.setAdapter(hstAdpt);
        listHistory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_history_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ClearPrefs();
                            logout();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryHeaderActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_home) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryHeaderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryHeaderActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void ClearPrefs() {
    }

    public void logout() {
        SharedPreferences preferences5 = getSharedPreferences("IDLOGIN", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor5 = preferences5.edit();
        editor5.clear();
        editor5.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try expandable ListView

Comment: no Sir @Rushi Ayyappa, I'm just want to add listview as much as the number of ID Header..

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: Have you tried PinnedHeaderListView : https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview

Comment: I want each listview can view patient data group by ID header.. So far, I add Search View (at method AddNewList).
But when I input one ID header to search view, all of listview view the same data according to ID header in that search view..

i'm not sure if it is the right way, please give some advice, Sir

Comment: i can't recognize your issue. Please give more details about it. if you want to group by by Id then you have to HashMap<String headerId,ArrayList<Data>> then use pinned-section-listview so you can identify.

Comment: I'm sorry if you cannot recognize, I have add image to make you more understand what I mean..

for example: 
we add id patient: 000516, 
(id patient 000516 have 3 ID Header, 
ID header1 have 2 items, iD header2 have 5 items and ID header 3 have 3 items.)
when click button, will appear 3 listview, like listview in image that I share.

Each listview consists of items but group by the 3 ID Headers..

Here I confuse.. I didn't know how the right way.. to view data in listview like I explain.. Hope you will give some advices Sir, @MavyaSoni

Comment: My suggestion is that do not use three listview for it. The one of best solution is that i have shared one link to you. In that link you will get same example which you have required. :  github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview

Comment: Okay, Sir @MavyaSoni I will try to use the link, hope you will wait the result of my trying. Thank you Sir..

Comment: thank you  for editing, Sir @Hey-men-whatsup

Comment: Okai, no problemo...

Comment: Hello, I finally found the best way to solve my problem. I use this tutorial:
[http://abhiandroid.com/ui/expandablelistadapter-example-android.html]

Comment: thank you Sir @MavyaSoni I didn't use more than one listview as you say.. Thank you..